# Build Does Not Break For Minor Version Change

Tags: maven

I'm testing out the Maven plug-in of [japicmp](https://github.com/siom79/japicmp):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.siom79.japicmp</groupId>
            <artifactId>japicmp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <oldVersion>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <version>${lastBaseVersion}</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                    </dependency>
                </oldVersion>
                <newVersion>
                    <file>
                        <path>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.${project.packaging}</path>
                    </file>
                </newVersion>
                <parameter>
                    <onlyModified>true</onlyModified>
                    <breakBuildBasedOnSemanticVersioning>true</breakBuildBasedOnSemanticVersioning>
                </parameter>
                <skip></skip>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>cmp</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

To test it out, I copied an existing project multiple times and added a method to an interface (i.e. broke the API).

The API break gets correctly reported if I only increment the patch version (1.0.0 -> 1.0.1), and gets correctly ignored for the major version (1.0.0 -> 2.0.0).

However, for a minor version change it is not reported. I'm probably overlooking something basic here, but the API break should be reported for minor version changes.

I checked the [manual](https://siom79.github.io/japicmp/MavenPlugin.html), but it only states: *"If set to true, the plugin analyzes the versions of the old and new archives and decides based on these versions if binary compatible or incompatible changes are allowed or not. This option expects versions in the form Major.Minor.Patch (e.g. 1.2.3 or 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT)."*

japicmp later links to [semver.org](http://semver.org/), which states: *"MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner"* - So a new method to an interface is clearly an API break.

If I remove the interface instead of adding a method, the build fails (as it should).

I found the test for this use-case: [CompatibilityChangesTest#testMethodAddedToInterface](https://github.com/siom79/japicmp/blob/master/japicmp/src/test/java/japicmp/compat/CompatibilityChangesTest.java): So it seems the problem is the setup, not the tooling itself.

What did I do? What did I overlook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a method to an interface is actually binary compatible because applications using your library don't know about the new method and hence do not call it. The JVM does not check at runtime if a class implements all methods defined in an interface, that is only done by the compiler.

The addition of a method to an interface is only source incomaptible. That means if you recompile your source code against the changed interface then the compilation fails because your class implementing the interface must now implement the new method.